# What is a good idiom for deceptive smile?

Tags: idioms

Is there a good idiom that implies fake happiness in the same way 'crocodile tears' imply fake sadness?

Comment: Are you thinking of *plastic smile?*

Comment: Could you add a little more context and show how you intend to use it?

Comment: I've definitely heard people say **"crocodile smile"** like this, though I can't find a definition. Makes sense since crocs often look like they're smiling but are seldom being friendly... Here's an example of a newspaper using it: [Forget Len McCluskey’s crocodile smile. Ed’s speech really was a historic moment](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/danhodges/100225777/forget-len-mccluskeys-crocodile-smile-eds-speech-really-was-a-historic-moment/)

Comment: Are you looking for deceptive as in the title, or fake?  One is "Please trust me while I screw you over", the other is "Please believe I'm happy"

Comment: How about "California Smile"? Or maybe "Hollywood Smile"...

Comment: @user568458: You need look no further than Lewis Carroll's ditty, "How Doth the Little Crocodile": 
    "How doth the little crocodile/
    Improve his shining tail,/
    And pour the waters of the Nile/
    On every golden scale!/

    How cheerfully he seems to grin,/
    How neatly spreads his claws,/
    And welcomes little fishes in/
    With gently smiling jaws!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not an idiom but you can say a ***sinister smile***.

Edit:
maybe too simple but: a ***fake smile***, or an ***empty smile***

Edit 2:
I just found this online at [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110803214019AAoZ083); I quite like this one:

> **Pan-Am smile** > It is named after the airline Pan American World Airways, whose flight attendants would always flash every jet-setter the same, perfunctory smile.
>
> Other alternative terms for a "fake smile" are: **Botox smile**, a **say-cheese smile**!
>
> A fake smile only involves the zygomatic major muscles which are forced by a person in order to give a polite smile. The smile is then limited only to the lips and there is no contraction in the eye area.
>
> The study of smiles is a part of gelotology, psychology, and linguistics.
>
> And it may be good to know that scientific word for a "real smile" is "Duchenne Smile" which is named after physician Guillaume Duchenne who first recognized the muscles involved with this smile.

Comment: close, but i think its too heavy on the negative connotation. A sinister smile does not imply the absence of joy, but rather the existence of an evil kind. :)

Comment: I updated my answer, but it seems to be lacking some *zing*

Comment: @guest1304 edited again...

Comment: I think there is such an expression as a 'joyless smile' isn't there?

Comment: @WS2 yeah there does seem to be such an expression - doesn't get a whole lot of g-hits though

Comment: RE: _'joyless smile' doesn't get a whole lot of g-hits though_... So what? Neither do _Pan-Am smile_ or _say-cheese smile_, but those are all interesting (and therefore good) answers.

Comment: Gives user3306356 a disingenuous smile, plus an upvote.

Comment: Nice answer, but I feel it's not complete without a reference to [Total Bastard Airlines](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xgu5tb_total-bastard-airlines_shortfilms).

Answer (score 11):

It depends what you're trying to convey. If it's a lack of emotion, or a lack of interest, it could be "a pale smile", "a polite smile", "a perfunctory smile", "a mechanical smile".

To suggest that it's regularly used, "a practised smile", "a receptionist's smile", "a salesman's smile", "a politician's smile".

If there is any negative intent, it could be "an intimidating smile", "an icy smile", "a debt-collector's smile"...

Answer (score 6):

Reading the comments and answers here I was reminded of an excerpt from Ralph Waldo Emerson's [*Self-Reliance*](http://books.google.com/books?id=rpWXsnSxr90C&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=emerson+self-reliance+forced+smile&source=bl&ots=5gqvXzqVmw&sig=fYbVk4M8jGjektZJRA-ry6SCdP4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NQlU4euDcO3rQGh-IHYBw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=emerson%20self-reliance%20forced%20smile&f=false):

> There is a mortifying experience in particular which does not fail to wreak itself also in the general history; I mean "**the foolish face of praise**," the **forced smile** which we put on in company where we do not feel at ease in answer to conversation which does not interest us. The muscles, not spontaneously moved, but moved by a low usurping willfulness, grow tight about the outline of the face with the most disageeable sensation... [A] man must know how to estimate a sour face... If this aversation had its origin in contempt and resistance like his own, he might well go home with a sad countenance; but **the sour faces of the multitude**, like their sweet faces, have no deep cause, but are put on and off as the wind blows and a newspaper directs.

Whatever the context, I think **forced smile** works, because the smile is as disingenuous as the "crocodile tears." The tears aren't coming from real sadness; this smile isn't coming from true happiness. Regardless of motive, the smile is not a reflection of how the smiling person feels. (The references I've found, though, tend to associate "forced smile" with one done from a non-hostile attitude.)

If the context matches Emerson's scenario -- where the smile comes more from polite obligation than how its wearer feels -- I recommend strengthening the reference by using *Emersionian*, as with:

1. The *Emersonian* "'foolish face of praise'"
2. The *Emersonian* "forced smile"
3. The *Emersonian* "sour faces (of the multitude)"

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the context -- and on whether it's an idiom for a deceptive (i.e. deceitful) smile or a fake smile that you're looking for -- you might want to consider the following phrases:

### ***Affected smiles:***

*put-on grin,  coated smile, made-up grin, plastered smile, placard smile, frontage smile, facade grin, storefront grin, meet & greet smile, front desk smile, greeter's smile, checkout smile, bogus grin, slick-perfect (or slick cover) grin, schoolmarmish/schoolma'amish grin, straitlaced smile, tight-laced smile, Pecksniffian smile, pharisaical smile, whited sepulcher-ish smile,  holier-than-thou smile*

> At the sound of her name, my mother offered a **[put-on](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put-on) grin** that
>   looked as if she had found the missing half of Cheney's smile.
>   [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Wyss0ybuLIUC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22put-on+grin%22&source=bl&ots=e1jC4eZwy-&sig=4U9CDQZ2nwhU4uB-DwhJO0TXqQo&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=zgYmU8HZD7Tw0gXrlYCoBw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22put-on%20grin%22&f=false)

There was a lot of anger in the house, but everybody kept it hidden behind a **coated smile** except Annie. [source](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7009932/4/The-Summer-Before-College)

> Throughout the narrative, the patient wore a **[plastered](http://www.ask.com/answers/56015041/does-plastered-smile-mean-) smile**.
>   [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Zvrq481PgFgC&pg=PR54&lpg=PR54&dq=%22plastered+smile%22&source=bl&ots=JTznH_BNDu&sig=8WZ_NIOjPCprNFCrrk6awfquBl4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=cAsnU5erBunX0QXCv4DIAw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22plastered%20smile%22&f=false)

Stoop waiting home with **frontage smile**... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=0hIiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22frontage+smile%22&source=bl&ots=cyyy8DZrQe&sig=0qbHRxX6thLv0LBGdOTp-yRNILQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=pwEnU_D6JMbI0QWx04GACQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22frontage%20smile%22&f=false)

> I can see the sweet sweat on your forehead, and the quivering falter
>   of your **facade grin**...
>   [source](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/bronies-beyond-the-stars-b-b-t-s.4407/page-4396)

No **meet & greet smile** and seems the employees are miserable also.[source](http://www.yelp.com/user_details?userid=ux4rA9sTpNnacMdh-_EhMg)

> A **front desk smile** might have been inviting!
>   [source](http://www.expedia.com/Indianapolis-Hotels-Drury-Inn-Indianapolis.h9790-p9.Hotel-Reviews)

Florio turned around, his **greeter's smile** on his face... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=3fvEtZoZPoEC&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=%22greeter%27s+smile%22&source=bl&ots=H49ysHZLlz&sig=UtlNvPdUSkDNG2ZBlUoK54x0lt0&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=_fMqU_-kBIOm0QX0mIGQAw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22greeter%27s%20smile%22&f=false)

> She hands me the bag and we smile a **checkout smile**.
>   [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=DPKHh4dqCCsC&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=%22checkout+smile%22&source=bl&ots=pYytGsuiR8&sig=f7CKpnUdlTJm9UbeogKxpLEdYUs&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=i5opU4YxhpvUBa6LAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22checkout%20smile%22&f=false)

The moment Charles entered the room with that **[bogus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bogus) grin** on his face... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=IqgiycDQeFUC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22bogus+grin%22&source=bl&ots=RFWFZKfguE&sig=neinUttYBIadj6uXOqWQWcMzBOE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=5gQmU6uBH6K30QXbsoD4Cg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22bogus%20grin%22&f=false)

> Displaying a **schoolmarmish grin** albeit with an unconvincing LA
>   inflection.
>   [source](http://authonomy.com/books/51510/sucker-punch/read-book/?chapterid=489215)
>   Opposing both, she flashed a **[schoolmarmish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schoolmarm) grin**...
>   [source](http://articles.sun-sentinel.com/1986-02-02/news/8601080237_1_town-council-town-issues-town-residents)

I ushered him in, a tight **[straitlaced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strait-laced)** smile as a greeting. [source](http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2013/09/03/11085536/First%204%20chapters%20of%20Trust%20Me.pdf)

> A falsely **[tight-laced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tight-laced) smile** spread over Hogarth's face.
>   [source](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4297504/51/The-Protector)

He would stretch forth a finger and help him with a **[Pecksniffian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pecksniffian) smile**. [source](https://archive.org/stream/wortlebankdiarys02leeh/wortlebankdiarys02leeh_djvu.txt)

> Outside of Chicago, we wear a **[pharisaical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pharisaical) smile**...
>   [source](http://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=LAH19081102.2.31),
>   [source](http://www.powell-pressburger.org/Reviews/ThreeNeglectedFilms.html)

A **[whited sepulchered](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whited+sepulcher) smirk** and oh so jaded. [source](http://www.forwardpoetry.co.uk/poem.php?id=5667), [source](https://etd.library.emory.edu/file/view/pid/emory%3abq3j9/gilbert_dissertation.pdf)

> She's so manipulative, with that **[holier-than-thou](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/holier-than-thou) smile**.
>   [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=M2c8l9Hl7uEC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22holier+than+thou+smile%22&source=bl&ots=uWKf8lgKop&sig=lIyUYzShBoIJY0RrQhzN-Dm1v2s&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Y5cmU7DDN6GI0AXr_oC4Bg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22holier%20than%20thou%20smile%22&f=false) 
>   [source](http://www.andoverfilmclub.org/index.php/film-schedule/52-0809-season/78-the-wave-1st-december)

---

### ***Deceptive smiles:***

*Sleek smile, phony smile, humbugging grin, carpetbagging smile, shyster's grin, con artist grin, huckster's grin, two-timing smile, double-crossing smile, two-faced smile, double-dealing smile*.

> The notice calling the meeting of protest gives a curious insight into
>   the war of angry emotions that may be hidden under the **[sleek](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sleek) smile**
>   of the supplest waiter.
>   [source](http://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=LAH19060325.2.111.38)

She had confessed, instantly, with her **[humbugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbug) grin**... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=fm-B1t8j40MC&pg=PT2234&lpg=PT2234&dq=%22humbugging+grin%22&source=bl&ots=k1YFdwoYyh&sig=Q44y5kgThLZhKIepwysHShPky9g&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Z1MoU-e1Ccih0QXapoGYDQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22humbugging%20grin%22&f=false)

> He still can't see the fat face hidden behind his glasses, behind a
>   **carpetbagging smile**. [source](http://www.rulit.net/books/blood-acre-read-218490-50.html)
>   http://www.encyclopediaofarkansas.net/encyclopedia/entry-detail.aspx?entryID=1179

"You should just go back to show everybody in there at least that you're alright", he said while flashing a **[shyster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shyster)'s smile**. [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=cQprKhovPIUC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%22shyster%27s+smile%22&source=bl&ots=mcWlD2dPdi&sig=VVQouirc76dPZtUjkzjuyKt2TkQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=8B0mU-qoFeLb0QXzzICwDA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22shyster%27s%20smile%22&f=false)
 [source](http://www.vivascene.com/featured-articles/pulling-focus-the-night-of-the-hunter/)

> She has never been so relieved to see that totally untrustworthy
>   *honey, I'm hip* **[huckster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/huckster)'s grin** on her husband's face... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=IBvPLv9KTYIC&pg=PT90&lpg=PT90&dq=%22hip+huckster%27s+grin%22&source=bl&ots=cMJlC5oRTq&sig=YNY3zC-0LlBlH1YNnRP7Vm2x0dg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Zz8mU-bgOMKj0QWd8oDQCQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22hip%20huckster%27s%20grin%22&f=false)
>   [source](http://nymag.com/nymetro/arts/books/reviews/n_8405/)

Girls manipulate and bully almost silently, often behind a **two-timing smile** that may show intentions to their classmates. [source](http://amandaloch.com/aggressioningirls/)

> Smiling her **double-crossing smile**, Regina offers to introduce
>   Sally to Aaron but smooches him instead.
>   [source](http://the.honoluluadvertiser.com/article/2004/Apr/30/en/en18a.html)

...at seeing baby's first smile -- and a dark side -- a **two-faced smile** in which the outward pleasantness camouflages a person's inner feelings. [source](http://bodyodd.nbcnews.com/_news/2011/09/08/7578410-read-my-lips-new-book-explores-a-smiles-subtleties) [source](http://www.filmclub.org/discover-more/details/256/the-night-of-the-hunter-reviewed-by-miriam-17)

Comment: Wow!  47 revisions.  This must be your favorite question!

Comment: @DavidM Guess what? There are more to come!

Comment: You've revised this so many times, it's flipped the switch into a community wiki.  So, you don't get any rep for it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a *cliche* than an idiom, but many writers use expressions like:

> The smile stopped at the corners of his mouth.

Based on the common observation that the difference between a fake and a genuine smile is in the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite ways of describing a deceptive smile was done by the legend George R.R. Martin himself:

"Littlefinger smiled with his mouth, but not his eyes"

Answer (score 1):

I would say **Grinning like Cheshire Cat** could be used.

> a constantly grinning cat in Lewis Carroll's Alice's Adventures in
>   Wonderland. grin like a Cheshire cat, to smile or grin inscrutably.
>   and its proverbial grin attested from 1770, of unknown origin. A cat
>   with an enormous grin encountered by Alice in Alice's Adventures in
>   Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll.

This would signify someone that is always smiling cheek-to-cheek in a pseudo-deceiving way.

Comment: +1, but it often implies a sense of self-satisfaction rather than falsehood.

Answer (score 1):

My daughter suggested 'Barbie smile' and 'the smile that comes with the fake laugh you do when someone tells a joke that isn't funny'. I thought I'd share.:)

Answer (score 1):

A tutored smile.

This phrase implies that the subject had to exert some effort and intention to exhibit a smile.

Comment: Did you mean tortured?

Answer (score 1):

"Opps! My mistake! I thought the topic was 'What is a good *Emoticon* for a deceptive smile?'".
**He smiled with a plastic grin** as he quickly exited the Stack Exchange Forum.

Answer (score 1):

From the Bill Murray comedy, "Quick Change," in which Murray's character is dressed as a clown, and in the process of robbing a bank he describes himself as a

> smiling on the outside, but crying on the inside kind of clown.

With a slight tweak,

> A smiling on the outside, but crying on the inside kind of smile.

Comment: Something about this answer reminds me of the distinction of "a smile from a veil" from Pink Floyd's song *Wish You Were Here*. I've always imagined it to mean something along these melancholic/sympathetic lines, though the lyricist could have had something entirely different in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not what you're after, but you could describe a smile without using the word 'smile' at all.  Perhaps refer to it as a grimace.  Then the reader will catch the sense of off-kilter falseness.

> His eyes caught mine and he held my gaze while the corners of his lips pulled up in a kind of grimace, showing his teeth.  After a second I realised this was a forced smile...

Answer (score 1):

I think the word **artificial** is appropriate here.

An *artificial* smile.

*Artificial* happiness.

**NB:** I think the title here is a bit *deceptive* because it asks for a *deceptive smile*, whereas the content of the question clarifies that the OP is looking for a word for:

> **fake** happiness in the same way 'crocodile tears' imply fake sadness

... and clearly the word *deceptive* has negative connotations unlike *fake* - which doesn't necessarily imply something negative.

Answer (score 1):

Overseas, this phenomenon is widely known as the *American smile*, but *plastic smile* (suggested in comments) is good too.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the word that seems to be missing from this long list is **mischievous**.

Saying that someone has a **mischievous smile/grin** fits the author's exact need.

Answer (score 0):

What I met in a few instances of fiction was

> Professional Smile Number Five

This emphasizes the smile is rehearsed, trained, routine, required by code, looks pleasant, and is completely irrelevant to whatever feelings the subject has. It's not so much sinisterly deceptive, as "hide own feelings, appear pleasant and professional".

Answer (score 0):

While it starts to fall under the area of trademarked terms, "Stepford smiler" is used pretty often in my experience, relating back to the novel (and movies), [*The Stepford Wives*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stepford_Wives). The drawback I see in that is that it carries a connotation that the smile is being enforced, in the case of the source material, through mental reprogramming, but sometimes mandated by parents or employers. I have also seen it in the context of a self-imposed constant smile despite not being happy, but it's rarer.

Answer (score 0):

wolfish grin? though it doesn't encompass every situation you've set out in your question.