# Is there a one word synonym for insincere smile?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a story in which the last two words are currently "fake smile." It would be punchier if I could condense these two words into one - is there any such word?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172914/what-is-a-word-for-a-person-who-throws-a-fake-smile)

Comment: Thanks! Although, that's someone who gives a fake smile - is there a word for the fake smile itself?

Comment: Yes, it's called a Pan Am smile (that was the first word used) or a Botox smile according to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile)

Comment: "Smirk" comes pretty close.  (I've never heard of "Pan Am smile", and "Botox smile" suggests someone whose face is frozen in a smile from botched cosmetic surgery.)

Answer (score 0):

We could derive *eccedentesism* from *eccedentesiast* which is a coinage of Florence King's for one who smiles such fake smiles.

I don't recommend you do though, as not enough people know *eccedentesiast* to be able to figure out *eccedentesism*.

I'd recommend the opposite, of being less direct rather than using a single word, "salesman smile", "Stepford smile", "customer services smile", "politician smile", "infomercial smile" and so on, depending on why they have such a fake smile at the story's end.

Comment: If it's _eccedentesiast_, shouldn't it be _eccedentesiasm_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet surely things are bad enough as it is!

Comment: I thought that was a stripper.

Comment: @HotLicks sometimes they are.