# What's a word for someone who likes and praises in front of others, but isn't that way normally to you?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call that phony person who favours and compliments you in front other people, such as your friends or family, but in general they normally aren't that way to you? They could be aloof and grim even without the company of these people.

I'm guessing "two-faced" or "phony" would seem the appropriate terms here, but is there something more specific and/or more suited?

Comment: Pick one in the linked answers. There is another one. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292965/one-word-for-a-person-who-pretends-to-be-nice-to-someones-face-but-makes-fun-of/293043#293043 You need to write an example sentence where the word would be used. That can help other users to come up with suggestios that can fit in your context.

Comment: Bless that guy for being sensible. "If you are satisfied, tell others. If not, tell us." What do you want?